# Search results are showing on 404.php page

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins

I'm making a WordPress plugin where I have created a custom search, search is working well but when it gets the result it shows on 404.php page as shown. How can I solve it
[image: As shown]

Answer (score 0):

Search results should be shown on a front page (site url). So, if your domain is `domain.com`, search results will be shown on `domain.com/?s=search_query`

Your form should have `action` leading to a home.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="GET">
  <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s">
</form>
```